# Unable to install indigo on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
i am new to ROS. I was trying to install ros-indigo-desktop-full on my ubuntu 14.04 64 bit machine as per the instruction at http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu. But i am having some issues :

baila@baila:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Please help me what to do! I am also attaching the output of uname.

baila@baila:~$ uname -m
x86_64
baila@baila:~$ uname -a
Linux baila 3.13.0-66-generic #108-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 15:20:27 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225196/unable-to-install-indigo-on-ubuntu-14.04/) by [baila](https://answers.ros.org/users/25509/baila/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2016-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-01-27**:
This happens because ros-indigo-desktop-full is trying to install other packages (dependencies) but those packages will conflict with some other packages that are already installed. You need to check the dependencies of the package listed and compare with the installed packages you have.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-01-27**:
Just in case, have you previously installed other ROS or Gazebo?

**Comment by [baila](https://answers.ros.org/users/25509/baila/) on 2016-01-27**:
No, i was trying this for first time. How to detect those conflicted packages?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-01-27**:
try with aptitude instead of apt-get and post the suggested solutions here. Be very careful before accepting anything there unless you study, what it wants to do.

**Comment by [baila](https://answers.ros.org/users/25509/baila/) on 2016-01-28**:
I tried with aptitude. It manages to install indigo, but i can't move forward with the test of existing projects. So i figured it out that there are graphics card driver related problem. I formatted my machine. And it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all. I kind of manage to solve this problem. I was having trouble with the nvidia graphics driver. I formatted my system and without installing any nvidia graphics driver, everything runs as expected.

However, i have 1GB Nvidia Geforce Cuda (520M) series graphics card in Lenovo Z570 laptop. I can't use my GPU. Can anyone have any solution for that?

---

Originally posted by [baila](https://answers.ros.org/users/25509/baila/) with karma: 32 on 2016-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0